# Map Object properties from another list

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

I have two lists below:

List students; where Student class is as below:

```
public class Student {
  private int id;
  private int addressId;
  private String name;
  private String address;
}

public class Address {
  private int id;
  private String address;
}

public class MapperClass {
  public void map(List<Student> students, Map<int, String> addresses ){
    //For each student, I want to take address from addresses map and update the Student class's address field. 
    // Below is sample code I have implemented
    students.forEach(s -> s.setAddress(addresses.get(s.getAddressId()))
  }
}
```

This implementation is working per expectation. But is there more optimized way for doing that instead of iterating through entire students list? I'll be having huge data in both map and students list.

Please share if I can use any libraries/algorithm can be used for this.

Thank you.

Comment: How else are you going to set an address for each student if you don't access each element of the list? "Access each element of the list" is what "iterating through entire students list" means. There is no way around this.

Comment: How would you apply changes to every student if you don't go through the complete list? Anyway, depending on the map implementation, compexity for the algorithm is between O(n) which is pretty good and O(n²). I would guess it tends to be on the better side of the scale if you don't do anything silly with the map.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for a solution where you don't need to keep every object in memory at the same time? In that case you should describe the data a bit more.

Comment: Yes, I will not be able to do it without iterating the whole list, but I just wanted to check if there is any readymade framework which is passed with key field, list and map, will map the values directly.

Comment: You can try and use parallel streams to enhance performance. [Here's](https://www.baeldung.com/java-when-to-use-parallel-stream) a tutorial.

Comment: There is one more performant way: Arrange the data store (e.g. a database) where you're getting these lists in such a way that it returns the data in one go (e.g. using a query with a JOIN). Exact implementation will vary based on the data store you're using.